# javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance() not found on Jetty and Java 7

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, el

I have this JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="http://localhost:8000/"/> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${contextPath}/css/styles.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- some html -->
</body>
```

When I navigate to this page, I get next error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;  
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.getExpressionFactory(JspUtil.java:1182) 
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.validateExpressions(JspUtil.java:644)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:752)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:946)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2341)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2347)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:498)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2291)
[...]
```

The environment to execute this page is Java 7 and Jetty.

If I remove ${contextPath} works fine.

Why i have this error?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your error is 2 different EL language jars in your classpath.

- EL version 2.1 is what is actively being used by your webapp, and is the cause of your error (that method doesn't exist in EL 2.1)
- EL version 2.2 is what your webapp needs to be using for `javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()`, as that method was introduced in EL 2.2

Make sure you are using the correct version of the EL lib, and that you don't have multiple versions of it present in your webapp

Also, why not just use ...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
      href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css"/>
```

and skip the whole `<c:set>` you are using? (your choice of a fully qualified URI is a bad idea anyway)

Comment: Works like a charm. The problem was that jsp library was added like provided and jetty-plugin has not added this library